# Formatting Json Response into an Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

Currently I am receiving a response like this from my API:

```
[{"$id":"1","accommodation_type":"apartment","max_people":2},{"$id":"2","accommodation_type":"lodge","max_people":5}]
```

I would like to format it so that the output removes all the unnecessary punctuation so that it looks more like this whilst also placing it into an Array.

```
id, 1, accommodation_type, apartment, max_people, 2, id, 2, accommodation_type, lodge, max_people 5
```

OR

```
1, apartment, 2, ,2, lodge, 5
```

Currently I have tried:

```java
String temp[]= AccommodationTypesStr.split(":|\\,|\\}"); // Where AccommodationTypesStr is the input json string
```

However between each row of data it leaves a empty space as a element in the array so its like:

```
id, 1, accomodation_type, apartment, max_people, 2,  ,id, 2, accommodation_type, lodge, max_people 5
```

Whilst also still having some brackets in the response.

I've messed around with JSON Object and Array but had no luck at all so was wondering if I could do it by formatting it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) to convert `json` string to some object, in this case like `List<Map<String, Object>>`. Then iterate over this list using `java stream api`.

Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Read `json` string value:

```java
String json = "[{\"$id\":\"1\",\"accommodation_type\":\"apartment\",\"max_people\":2},{\"$id\":\"2\",\"accommodation_type\":\"lodge\",\"max_people\":5}]";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Map<String, Object>> list = mapper.readValue(json, List.class);
```

Then iterate over this list:

```java
List<Object> flatList = list.stream()
    .flatMap(element -> element.values().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(flatList); // [1, apartment, 2, 2, lodge, 5]
```

Or more detailed variant:

```java
List<Object> flatList = list.stream()
    .map(Map::values)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(flatList); // [[1, apartment, 2], [2, lodge, 5]]
```

And more:

```java
List<Object> flatList = list.stream()
    .flatMap(element -> element.entrySet().stream())
    .flatMap(entry -> Stream.of(
        entry.getKey().replace("$", ""), // without "$"
        entry.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(flatList);
// [id, 1, accommodation_type, apartment, max_people, 2, id, 2, accommodation_type, lodge, max_people, 5]
```

---

In general, you can write your own flattening algorithm. For example:

- [«Flatten nested Map containing with unknown level of nested Arrays and Maps recursively»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62733833/11141611).
- [«Restoring a value tree from its flat map representation»](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62763040/11141611).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a POJO class and then use libraries like Jackson or Gson to map the JSON string into an array of POJO instances. In this case I will use Jackson you can import it via maven with:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The POJO class. Note that I use the annotation `@JsonProperty` to set the JSON field names so I can avoid using variable names that contain special characters.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class APIResponse {

    @JsonProperty("$id")
    private int id;

    @JsonProperty("accommodation_type")
    private String accommodationType;

    @JsonProperty("max_people")
    private int maxPeople;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getMaxPeople() {
        return maxPeople;
    }

    public String getAccommodationType() {
        return accommodationType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "APIResponse{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", accommodationType='" + accommodationType + '\'' +
                ", maxPeople=" + maxPeople +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Then you can deserialize using:

```java
final String json = "[{\"$id\":\"1\",\"accommodation_type\":\"apartment\",\"max_people\":2},{\"$id\":\"2\",\"accommodation_type\":\"lodge\",\"max_people\":5}]";
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
APIResponse[] responses = mapper.readValue(json, APIResponse[].class);
for (APIResponse response: responses) {
    System.out.println(response.toString());
}
```

Result:

```
APIResponse{id=1, accommodationType='apartment', maxPeople=2}
APIResponse{id=2, accommodationType='lodge', maxPeople=5}
```

Finally, you can access the data just by calling the getters in the POJO class:

```java
responses[0].getId(); // 1
responses[1].getAccommodationType; // lodge
```

Then if you want the data separated by commas use:

```java
public String[] getByComas(APIResponse[] responses) {
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (APIResponse response: responses) {
        data.add("id,");
        data.add(response.getId() + ",");
        data.add("accommodation_type,");
        data.add(response.getAccommodationType() + ",");
        data.add("max_people,");
        data.add(response.getMaxPeople() + ",");
    }
    return data.toArray(new String[data.size()]);
}
```

Then just use:

```java
String[] formattedMessage = getByComas(responses);
for (String s: formattedMessage) {
    System.out.print(s);
}
```

Result:

```
id,1,accommodation_type,apartment,max_people,2,id,2,accommodation_type,lodge,max_people,5,
```

Using JSON mappers is highly recommended as they are pretty reliable when parsing JSON data.

Let me know if this solves your problem!