# JSONObject to ArrayList square brackets missing

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I am trying to get the rates from `https://api.ratesapi.io/api/latest` into an `ArrayList<Currency>` of a custom `Currency` class:

```java
public class Currency {
    private String shortName;
    private double rate;
    ...
}
```

The JSON looks like:

```
{"base":"EUR","rates":{"GBP":0.90033,"HKD":9.1786,"IDR":17304.0,
 "ILS":4.0309,"DKK":7.45,"INR":88.765,"CHF":1.0759,"MXN":26.615,
 "CZK":26.202,"SGD":1.6236,"THB":36.832,"HRK":7.468,"MYR":4.9604,
 "NOK":10.6538,"CNY":8.2325,"BGN":1.9558,"PHP":58.136,"SEK":10.3165,
 "PLN":4.4073,"ZAR":20.7655,"CAD":1.5748,"ISK":160.2,"BRL":6.334,
 "RON":4.836,"NZD":1.7828,"TRY":8.5853,"JPY":124.96,"RUB":86.9321,
 "KRW":1404.99,"USD":1.1843,"HUF":346.23,"AUD":1.6492},"date":"2020-08-06"}
```

Using `org.json` I managed to get the data into a `JSONObject`:

```java
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(getJSON("https://api.ratesapi.io/api/latest"));
```

As far as I understand, the normal procedure is now to convert the `JSONObject` into a `JSONArray`. However trying:

```java
JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("rates");
```

fails with the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["rates"]
is not a JSONArray.
```

How do I fix this error or is there another way to make an ArrayList out of the JSON?

I suspect that the problem are missing square brackets in the JSON string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [simplest way to read json from a URL in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308554/simplest-way-to-read-json-from-a-url-in-java)

Comment: @KaustubhKhare while related, that dupe isn't going to help OP because the class they want to parse into does not match the structure of the JSON content.

Comment: This is closer https://stackoverflow.com/q/22687771/1690217 the issue is that `rates` is an object with the _properties_ that match your `Currency` structure, you need to convert the `rates` object into an array of it's properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the JSON returned by the API, you get a JSON object:

```
{"base":"EUR","rates":{"GBP":0.90033,"HKD":9.1786, ... },"date":"2020-08-06"}
```

You probably want to do something like this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(getJSON("https://api.ratesapi.io/api/latest"));
JSONObject rates = obj.getJSONObject("rates");
final Iterator<String> keys = rates.keys();
while (keys.hasNext()) {
  final String key = keys.next();
  final Currency currency = new Currency(key, rates.getDouble(key));
  // do something with the Currency
}
```

Comment: @user1583209 as you're working with currency data I'd advice not to use double for the computation. Instead use `BigDecimal` to avoid rounding issues. Something like `new BigDecimal(rates.getString(key))` will probably do

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) class to convert `json` from some `URL` to some kind of object. In this case (if `json` structure is always the same) it can be `Map<String, Object>`.

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
URL url = new URL("https://api.ratesapi.io/api/latest");
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(url, Map.class);

System.out.println(map);
// {base=EUR, rates={GBP=0.90373, HKD=9.1585, ... , AUD=1.6403}, date=2020-08-07}
```

Then you can get inner `rates` map, and (if it is needed) convert it to list using `java stream api`:

```java
Map<String, Double> rates = (Map<String, Double>) map.get("rates");

System.out.println(rates); // {GBP=0.90373, HKD=9.1585, ... , AUD=1.6403}
```

Convert `Map<String, Object>` to `ArrayList<Currency>`:

```java
ArrayList<Currency> list = rates.entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> new Currency(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
    .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);

System.out.println(list); // [GBP=0.90373, HKD=9.1585, ... , AUD=1.6403]
```

*Note:* add a constructor with two fields `shortName` and `rate`;

*Note:* override the `toString` method as follows: `shortName + "=" + rate`;

---

Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

---

<sup>See also: [«Formatting Json Response into an Array Java»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63221994/11141611).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The object "`rates`" is not a JSONArray, is a JSONObject.

So you have to do `obj.getJSONObject(rates");`then iterate on the fields of the JSONObject using map methods (for examply using keySet() )

Answer (score 2):

A working solution using Jackson library and Lombok may be as follows:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import lombok.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CcyApiParser {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    public static class Currency {
        private String shortName;
        private double rate;
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class RatesApiResponse {
        private String base;
        private Map<String, Double> rates;
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        private LocalDate date;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()); // to parse date

        URL apiUrl = new URL("https://api.ratesapi.io/api/latest");
    
        // read proper api response
        RatesApiResponse rates = mapper.readValue(apiUrl, RatesApiResponse.class);

        // convert inner rates into list of Currency objects
        List<Currency> ccys = rates.getRates().entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> new Currency(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        ccys.forEach(ccy -> System.out.printf("%s=%s%n", ccy.getShortName(), ccy.getRate()));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
GBP=0.90033
HKD=9.1786
IDR=17304.0
ILS=4.0309
... etc.
```

**Update**

It is also possible to customize deserialization of RatesApiResponse and move mapping of `"rates"` into this class to convert immediately into list of currencies.

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class RatesApiResponse {
        private String base;
        @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
        private List<Currency> ccys;

        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        private LocalDate date;

        // no getter for rates
        // this customized setter for the map of rates converts into a list
        @JsonProperty("rates")
        public void setRates(Map<String, Double> rates) {
            ccys = rates.entrySet().stream()
                    .map(e -> new Currency(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }

// Updates in the test method
RatesApiResponse rates = mapper.readValue(src, RatesApiResponse.class);

rates.getCcys().forEach(ccy -> System.out.printf("%s=%s%n", ccy.getShortName(), ccy.getRate()));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["rates"]
> is not a JSONArray.

You got this error because `rates` is not in the form of an array. It is simply an element like `base` and `date` but looks like an array. Get it from the JSON string like you get  `base` and `date` from it and then process it to create the required `List<Currency>`.

Given below is the working code with the explanation added as comments in the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

class Currency {
    private String shortName;
    private double rate;

    public Currency(String shortName, double rate) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return shortName + ":" + rate;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static JSONObject getJSON(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
        // Create a URLConnection for the given URL
        URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();

        // Add header to avoid 403 Forbidden HTTP status code
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0" + "");

        StringBuilder jsonStr = new StringBuilder();

        // Get InputStream from connection and read the response
        try (InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();) {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

            int ch;
            while ((ch = reader.read()) != -1) {
                jsonStr.append((char) ch);
            }
        }
        return new JSONObject(jsonStr.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObj = getJSON("https://api.ratesapi.io/api/latest");

        // Get rates from jsonObj
        String rates = jsonObj.get("rates").toString();

        // Remove {, }, and " from the string
        String[] keyValArr = rates.replaceAll("[\\{\\\"}]", "").split(",");

        // List object to hold Currency objects
        List<Currency> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String keyVal : keyValArr) {
            // Split each key:value string on ':'
            String[] curRate = keyVal.split(":");

            // Add Currency object to List
            list.add(new Currency(curRate[0], Double.parseDouble(curRate[1])));
        }

        // Display list
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
CHF:1.0804
HRK:7.4595
MXN:26.5127
...
...
...
NZD:1.7786
BRL:6.3274
```

Comment: **Note:** I used the Firefox plugin, [HTTP Header Live](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/http-header-live/) in order to get the value for the header, `User-Agent`.